# Date comparison between specific date formats in xquery

Tags: xquery

I have two dates; date1 = 2021-01-14T00:00:00-05:00 and date2 = 2021-01-17T00:00:00-05:00.
is there a good way to compare them in xquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can simply do

```
 xs:dateTime('2021-01-14T00:00:00-05:00') 
 < xs:dateTime('2021-01-17T00:00:00-05:00')
```